# Excel pivot table sum distinct values

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a question to ask about summing distinct sums. I have a table as below which is coming from a database

```
ID  |Activity |Rank| Max Rank|Health    Aggregated_$    Tiering   Engaged   Quarter
1   |Activty3 |3   |8        |1            100         4 - Lowest   Y   FY18 Q4
1   |Activty3 |3   |8        |2            100         4 - Lowest   Y   FY18 Q1
1   |Activty4 |4   |8        |1            100         4 - Lowest   Y   FY18 Q4
1   |Activty2 |2   |8        |1            100         4 - Lowest   Y   FY18 Q3
1   |Activty8 |8   |8        |1            100         4 - Lowest   Y   FY18 Q3
```

I am trying to get the sum distinct $ in each activity. Therefore, what I am trying to achieve is something like this in a pivot. The reason why I have to use the pivot is because Quarter is used as a filter to get only certain  quarters (FY 18 and beyond for example)

```
Activity  |   100
Activity2 |   100
Activity3 |   100
Activity4 |   100
Activity8 |   100
```

My pivot looks like this now. Was wondering if a sumproduct would work on this?

[image]

Comment: Distinct is typically associated with counting, not summing. It does not make sense to "sum distinct". To achieve what you describe, you would need to add a column to your data source that identifies the distinct rows. How you would build the logic for that is not clear, though, since all rows in your source seem to be distinct, if all columns are evaluated.

Answer (score -1):

I would add a column in your data set next to your `$` field and do a formula in an adjacent cell to divide the `$` by the number of records which meet the criteria; in this case "`Activity`".

For example, if `Aggregate` field is in `column B` and `Activity` is in `Column A`, I would type in cell `C2`this formula `=B2/countif($A:$A, $A2)`. This will divide each value in `B2` by the number of times each specific activity occurs, thereby evenly distributing the sum across the number of records.

You can then pivot this new field in values and in essence get the true value for `distinct sum`. My `$.02`.